# Geographical distance between all points greater than a value with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, math, geospatial, computational-geometry

From a list of restaurants with a latitude and a longitude, how can I get points that have at least *X* km between all of them?

I mean, that each restaurant doesn't has any other restaurant in a radius of *X* km.

I tried the next query:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    lat as x, 
    lng as y,
    concat(ceil((lat+90)/5),',',ceil((lng+180)/5)) as groupParam
FROM 
    restaurants 
GROUP BY groupParam
```

And the result is this:

[image: result of the query]

In that query I'm grouping by a rounded latitude and longitude (ex: "12,23"). So I only get a node from (lat >= 12 && lat <13) and (lng >= 23 && lng < 24).

Thats fast but not very accurate.

Thanks,
Wiliam.

Comment: Hope it helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586708/get-results-that-fall-within-marker-radiuses-from-database

Answer (score 0):

I did some lon/lat calculations for a hamradio database I wrote as an webapp:
http://dk7sl.de/iRelais

Here is the select statement, where $x and $y are my lon/lat coordinates.
maximum distance is set to 15 km. You could switch to miles if you just remove the '*1.609344' in the query. This query selects the nearest entry in the geodata table.
Geodata was taken from http://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database/free and contains approx 2.4 million records in my mysqldb. DB-Indexes are on latitude, longitude, feature class and feature code (but that's just because I filter the entries by feature class and code)

$query = "SELECT name, (((ACOS(SIN('".$x."' * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(".$x." * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(('".$y."' - longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515))*1.609344 AS `distance` FROM `geodata` WHERE `feature class` = 'P' AND (`feature code` = 'PPLX' OR `feature code` = 'PPL') HAVING `distance`<='15' ORDER BY `distance` ASC LIMIT 1;";

maybe you can use my select statement and modify it so you get the right group of points out of your database.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your original question:**

I think this will provide you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id AS a,
    b.id AS b,
    ACOS(
        SIN(a.lat) * SIN(b.lat) + COS(a.lat) * COS(b.lat) * COS(a.lon - b.lon)
    ) * 6371.01 AS km
FROM 
    restaurants a,
    restaurants b
WHERE
    b.id > a.id AND
    ACOS(
        SIN(a.lat) * SIN(b.lat) + COS(a.lat) * COS(b.lat) * COS(a.lon - b.lon)
    ) * 6371.01 >= X
ORDER BY
    ACOS(
        SIN(a.lat) * SIN(b.lat) + COS(a.lat) * COS(b.lat) * COS(a.lon - b.lon)
    );
```

where X is the minimum kilometers you want between them.

Unfortunately, this type of query is a [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) returning a [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), so with 10 restaurants, you'll have 36 comparisons, 100 you'll have 4,851, 1,000 you'll have 498,501, etc.

**Answer to your revised question:**

To find all restaurants that are at least X kilometers away from any other restaurant, use this:

```
SELECT
    a.id AS a,
    MIN(ACOS(
        SIN(a.lat) * SIN(b.lat) + COS(a.lat) * COS(b.lat) * COS(a.lon - b.lon)
    ) * 6371.01) AS km
FROM 
    restaurants a,
    restaurants b
WHERE
    b.id > a.id
GROUP BY
    a.id
HAVING
    MIN(ACOS(
        SIN(a.lat) * SIN(b.lat) + COS(a.lat) * COS(b.lat) * COS(a.lon - b.lon)
    ) * 6371.01) >= X
ORDER BY
    MIN(ACOS(
        SIN(a.lat) * SIN(b.lat) + COS(a.lat) * COS(b.lat) * COS(a.lon - b.lon)
    ) * 6371.01)
```

where X is the minimum kilometers you want between them.

Comment: Thanks, but I want 150 km between all of them, I mean, with (A,B,C) there can be 150km between A-B, B-C but that not guarantees A-C.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. You want the sum of the distances between restruants A, B and C to be 150kms or greater? That isn't what you originally asked.