# Exact distance between two points in MySQL Spatial table in KMs

Tags: php, mysql, spatial

Greetings.

I have seen a few posts and answers on this topic, but I think the result given might not be really accurate.

Let's say I have rows with different points with Longitude and Latitude, in a MySQL spatial table. I just want to retrieve the distance between them, with a simple SELECT query. I have tried:

```
GLENGTH(
        LINESTRINGFROMWKB(
            LINESTRING(
                GEOMFROMTEXT(
                    ASTEXT(
                        POINTFROMWKB(
                            POINT( X(user_location) , Y(user_location))))),
                GEOMFROMTEXT(
                    ASTEXT(
                        POINTFROMWKB(
                            POINT( $latitude, $longitude )))))))*100
```

I know its kind of 'ugly', and I'm afraid the result is not given in KiloMeters.

How am I supposed to do this? Many thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to format your formula so it's readable. Also, what you're looking for is known as the "haversine" or "great circle" distance formula.

Comment: Also: it depends on how accurate you need to be. If you're doing a store-finder application, the haversine formula is fine.  If you're doing an engineering plan for a bridge, you need to learn about cartographic projections; the earth isn't perfectly spherical.

Answer (score 3):

Method you are using will not give you accurate results at all. Since [GLENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_glength) uses the simple Cartesian distance formula. You can as well read in the comments [here on GLENGTH's MySQL page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_glength) that it cant be used on Spherical surfaces, it is there for Cartesian plane.

In this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586708/get-results-that-fall-within-marker-radiuses-from-database/11587424#11587424), there is a modified formula and how to use it explained clearly, have a look at it. You will need to modify that to suit your purpose. But it will definitely guide you on how to proceed.

Hope it helps...